# Ugly lack of spacing in HMP section when a post has triple-digit votes

Tags: bug, design, community-bulletin

I noticed that, while I was viewing a SO post, in the Hot Meta Posts section, the vote count and the question title are bumped up right against each other:

[image: HMP section with triple-digit vote count bumped up against question title]

Comment: Oh wow, so it's old.  Sorry, this is my third dupe today -- I just can't find them like y'all can :(